# Riemann Hypothesis and Prime Count

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Let $\pi(a)$ be the number of primes below $a>0$. The prime number theorem states $\pi(a)\sim\frac{a}{\ln a}$. My question is trivial. Is $$\frac{a}{\ln a}\leq\pi(a)\leq\frac{a}{\ln a}+c\sqrt{a}\ln a$$ for some constant $c>0$ iff the Riemann Hypothesis holds true? Is there an easy proof?

Comment: Helge von Koch proved in 1901 that $|Li(x)-\pi(x)|<k\ln x \sqrt{x}$ assuming RH. I haven't seen this expressed in terms of $x/\ln x.$ If you found this idea somewhere it would be good to include the cite.

Comment: $Li(a)\sim \frac{a}{\ln a}$?

Comment: Oh I see..... hmmm... So $Li(a)~\frac{a}{\ln a}k(a)$ where $k(a)$ is a slow growing function of $a$.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your $k(a)$, which does not converge. Did you mean something different?

Answer (score 4):

The other answer is completely false, unfortunately. RH is equivalent to
\[\pi(x) - \mathrm{Li}(x) = O(\sqrt{x} \log x).\]
Now it is not hard to show that
\[\mathrm{Li}(x) = \frac{x}{\log x} \sum_{k=0}^{m - 1}{\frac{k!}{(\log x)^k}} + O\left(\frac{x}{(\log x)^{m + 1}}\right)\]
for any $m \geq 0$ (just use the definition of $\mathrm{Li}(x)$ and repeated integration by parts). Thus
\[\pi(x) = \frac{x}{\log x} \sum_{k=0}^{m - 1}{\frac{k!}{(\log x)^k}} + O\left(\frac{x}{(\log x)^{m + 1}}\right).\]
In particular, taking $m = 3$ yields
\[\pi(x) - \frac{x}{\log x} = \frac{x}{(\log x)^2} + \frac{2x}{(\log x)^3} + O\left(\frac{x}{(\log x)^4}\right).\]
So unconditionally we have that
\[\pi(x) \geq \frac{x}{\log x} + \frac{x}{(\log x)^2}\]
for all sufficiently large $x$, which contradicts the claimed inequality.

Comment: No, that's the only mistake - unfortunately the issue was that that mistake falsely suggested that the conjectured inequality was true!

Answer (score 2):

The original question:

> Let $\pi(a)$ be the number of primes below $a>0$. The prime number theorem states $\pi(a)\sim\frac{a}{\ln a}$. My question is trivial. Is $$\frac{a}{\ln a}\leq\pi(a)\leq\frac{a}{\ln a}+c\sqrt{a}\ln a$$ for some constant $c>0$ iff the Riemann Hypothesis holds true? Is there an easy proof?

This is an answer to the question as originally posted.

The question is whether it is true that $|\pi(x)-\frac{x}{\log x}|= O(\sqrt{x}\log x).$ It seemed you had seen this somewhere but the usual statement from Schoenfeld$^1$ assuming RH is that $|\pi(x)-Li(x)|=O(\sqrt{x}\log x).$ My point in the comment was that the suggestion

$$Li(x)\sim \frac{x}{\log x} \implies |\pi(x)-\frac{x}{\log x}|=O(\sqrt{x}\log x)$$

is wrong although the right-hand side might well be true.

Assume RH and so also from Schoenfeld we have $\vartheta(x)-x = O(\sqrt{x}\log^2 x).$ Then

$$|\pi(x)-\frac{x}{\log x}|= \frac{\vartheta(x)-x}{\log x}+\int\frac{\vartheta(t)}{t\log^2 t}dt =\int\frac{\vartheta(t)}{t\log^2 t}dt +\frac{O(\sqrt{x}\log^2 x)}{\log x}$$

$$=|\pi(x) -\frac{x}{\log x}|= O\left(\frac{x}{\log^2 x}\right)+  O(\sqrt{x}\log x) $$

**EDIT:** I overlooked the integral term in my original answer. The answer to the original question is that the claim is false.

Lowell Schoenfeld, Sharper Bounds for the Chebyshev Functions $\theta(x)$ and $\psi(x)$ (part II), Math. of Computation, vol. 30, no.134 (1976)

Comment: I think you assumed RH here, answer here gives "if RH then..." part. So converse is "...hence RH holds" types.

Comment: If $|π(x)−Li(x)|$ satisfies converse, then this also does it. I am pretty sure $|π(x)−Li(x)|$ bounded by $O(\sqrt x\ln x)$ implies Riemann Hypothesis holds.

Comment: You've completely ignored the term $\int \frac{\theta(t)}{t\log^2t}\,dt$, which has size $\frac x{\log^2 x}$.